# For some reason I cannot make Promises to block waiting for input

Tags: javascript

I'm porting some BASIC programs to Javascript, and I need an INPUT-like statement. My output "console" is a **pre id="output"** HTML element. I'm adding the output as text nodes inside the **pre** element.

My INPUT-like routine adds a **input type="text" length="50"** element to the output, and should wait for the text from the user until Enter key is pressed, and then the input element is removed. Supposedly I read the Promise definition in Mozilla, saw tons of related examples, but now I'm four hours and counting on this, and I'm feeling like I hit my head on the wall.

Even put the promise in an async function and used return await new Promise, etc, ect.

What I'm doing wrong? Tested with Firefox 78.7.1

```
function print(str)
{
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
}

function input()
{
    var input_element = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var promise;
    var input_str;

    print("? ");
    input_element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input_element.setAttribute("length", "50");
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(input_element);
    input_str = undefined;
    new Promise(function (resolve) {
        input_element.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                resolve(input_element.value);
        });
    }).then(function (str) { input_str = str; });
    document.getElementById("output").removeChild(input_element);
    print(input_str);
    print("\n");
    return input_str;
}
```

The first answer helped me, but now I don't see how to return the string correctly. It always returns with input_str == undefined because doesn't wait for user to enter the string.

```
function input()
{
    var input_element;
    var input_str;

    new Promise(function (resolve) {
        input_element = document.createElement("INPUT");

        print("? ");
        input_element.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input_element.setAttribute("length", "50");
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(input_element);
        input_str = undefined;
        input_element.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                resolve(input_element.value);
        });
    }).then(function (str) {
        input_str = str;
        document.getElementById("output").removeChild(input_element);
        print(input_str);
        print("\n");
    });
    return input_str;
}
```

EDIT: Finally understood it, the Promise is a kind of subthread that runs in their own, same for async functions. So what I did (with help of @kuvos) after grasping the concept, was to create an async function main() to contain the whole BASIC code and call input function using a = await input(). You can see the final code at https://github.com/nanochess/basic-computer-games/tree/main/03%20Animal/javascript

Comment: Move everything after the `.then` *into* the `.then`

Comment: It works very well but doesn't return the string in right time. It returns undefined immediately while waiting for input.